# Cannot append data to a binary file with code?

Tags: java, io

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
public class AppendBinaryFile
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        FileOutputStream toFile = null;
        try
        {
            toFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("numbers.dat"), true);
            toFile.write(15);
            toFile.write(30);
            toFile.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I run another program to get the data from a binary file after running the program but data in the binary file does not change. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: inside of your catch block put e.printStackTrace() ; and find is there any error.don't leave catch block empty ever

Comment: I just add the code but the program does not return any error.

Comment: try to give full path.may be file not exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your file output stream I believe.

Comment: I added close() but it does not change anything

Comment: toFile.flush();toFile.close();

Comment: Try flush after writing before closing. Also, you are catching the exception but doing nothing. Do a print out at least because it may be an exception.

Comment: @fastsnail Ah you beat me to it!

Comment: Is the file you are writing to already created or is it new? If it already exists, are the old contents still the same?